# Android Studio, how to get image in drawable through url

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to image in run time in android studio..

in that case eclipse has provide that code. I have pass image name in  imagename and then get image in drawable.

```
       companyLogo.setImageResource(getResourse.getIdentifier
      ("com.example.moneymanagement:drawable/"+imagename,null,null));
```

how to find that case in android studio.. this code has not accepted in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this code is working perfect please check package name in your project. because if package name are wrong then drawable are not found .

```
  companyLogo.setImageResource(getResourse.getIdentifier
  ("com.example.braingame:drawable/"+imagename,null,null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to make this easier, Picasso is a good one : http://square.github.io/picasso/
It automatically loads the image in background and caches it to optimize network calls.

Comment: No i have not use any other library.. only for code.